# Grouping Columns with DT Package in R

Tags: r, datatable, dt, formattable

Is there a way to group columns into "main" headings using the [dt](/questions/tagged/dt) package in [r](/questions/tagged/r) (or even the formattable package for that matter)? I have created an example of what I have been trying to do but cannot seem to find a [function](/questions/tagged/function) for it anywhere. I am making a table for a [shiny](/questions/tagged/shiny) Web App so it appears I may have to customize the CSS, although I'm not sure that is possible. To be clear, the `Historical` and `Current` headers are what I would like to replicate in my [datatable](/questions/tagged/datatable).

Example Data Table
[image]

For purposes of example, the following df would be split into two groupings under the same data frame with 1:4 being labelled under `Historical` and 5:8 being labelled under `Current`.

```
df <- data.frame(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
```

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could achieve that using Custom Table Container (see here: https://rstudio.github.io/DT/) and some JS (jQuery) to modify table CSS style.

```
# a custom table container
sketch = htmltools::withTags(table(
  class = 'display',
  thead(
# Define the grouping of your df
    tr(
      th(colspan = 4, 'Historical'),
      th(colspan = 4, 'Current')
    ),
# Repeat column names 8 times
    tr(
      lapply(paste0("Col ", 1:8), th)
    )
  )
))
# Using JS for adding CSS, i.e., coloring your heading
# Get the corresponding table header (th) from a table cell (td) and apply color to it
headjs <- "function(thead) {
  $(thead).closest('thead').find('th').eq(0).css('background-color', '#D9E1F2');
   $(thead).closest('thead').find('th').eq(1).css('background-color', '#8EA9DB');

}"

# Your data frame
df <- data.frame(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)

# Output DT with your custom header
datatable(df , container = sketch,  options = list(
  headerCallback = JS(headjs)
))
```

And the output:

[image]

Comment: Hi Miha! Ive been using your codes. Are the headers supposed to be centered automatically, or is this something we specify explictly?

Comment: @Serkan, no by default headers are aligned, character headers are aligned to the left  and numeric columns are always aligned to the right. The "Historical" and "Current" are centered due to the fact that table cell spans four columns (`colspan` argument).

Comment: Oh! Thank you for the clarification! How do I center align the headers then? Can you answer this here, or should I post a question?

Comment: `datatable(df , container = sketch, options = list(headerCallback = JS(headjs), columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-center', targets = "_all"))))`

Comment: Thank you for this! I will test it asap.

Comment: Nope - this didnt work for me. I guess Ill post a question at some point! :-)

Comment: Is there a way to have these headers included in the Excel button export?

Comment: Try adding `class = "dt-center"` to `th()` to center.